# Nginx can't find file i specified using a path

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm trying to serve a user a file using Nginx and later on when I figured out this problem first, then serve it with a protected url. Right now I have some code which specifies the path to the file the user wants to download. However my browser returns `File not found`.

My views

```
def download_item(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Usertasks, pk=pk)
    output_path = item.OutputPath
    response = HttpResponse()
    print(output_path)
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(output_path)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = output_path
    return response
```

My terminal prints out

> Not Found:
>   /home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/output/123.txt

and this path is correct and the filename is `123.txt` for testing purposes

Nginx sites-enabled config

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
     server unix:///home/django/copypaste/cleanup/usegolem.sock; # for a file socket
 #   server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 127.0.0.1; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 250M;   # adjust to taste



    location /static {
        alias /home/django/copypaste/cleanup/static/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/django/copypaste/cleanup/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }

    location /media {
        internal;
        root /home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var;
    }   

}
```

Also when a user clicks download it redirects to a download url that looks like this.

```
path('download/<int:pk>/', views.download_item, name='item-download'),
```

Could it be this causing an issue because Nginx wants to go to that url but that is not the webserver path to the file?

Comment: Does that configuration actually work? You should test it using `nginx -t` and `nginx -T` You appear to have two locations called `/media`.

Comment: Yes it works, but you're right that here is 2 /media's i didn't notice that. I will fix that right away! Thanks